# R blogdown::serve_site() doesn't generate "public" folder when using Hugo "gesquive/slate" theme

Tags: r, r-markdown, hugo, blogdown

I am trying to create a new blogdown project, and I've been using Yihui Xie's [wonderful documentation](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/) to get started.

**This works as expected:**
Wen I run the below code, I see a live representation of the [demo page](https://academic-demo.netlify.com/), and the `public` folder is generated in my local directory.

```
library(blogdown)
blogdown::new_site(theme = "gcushen/hugo-academic")
blogdown::build_site()
blogdown::serve_site()
```

[image]

**This does not work as expected:**
But when I re-run using the  "gesquive/slate" theme, I see a live representation of the [demo page](https://gesquive.github.io/hugo-slate-demo/) as expected, but no `public` folder is generated in my local directory.  Without a `public` folder, I have nothing to send to Netlify.

```
library(blogdown)
blogdown::new_site(theme = "gesquive/slate")
blogdown::build_site()
blogdown::serve_site()
```

[image]

**Why is a `public` folder generated when I use any Hugo theme other than "gesquive/slate"?**

I expect that I'm misunderstanding something about how the package works with Hugo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the theme [config.toml](https://github.com/gesquive/hugo-slate-demo/blob/master/config.toml), the published folder (*publishDir*) is "docs", you can rename it to "public" if you wish.

Comment: Wow, I got so hung up on trying to find "public" that I failed to make that connection. Thank you!

Comment: It happens to all of us. Happy Blogdown.